# Grid Search Combined with Random Search

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, hyperparameter

Is there a way to combine both grid search and random search together ?

Lets say I provided a very big range of hyper parameters, can I use random search to minimize this range, and then I follow it back with grid search over this minimized range ? If yes what is the exact methodology to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do it is taking random samples across the space and creating additional grids at a finer resolution where your performance is good. Another way is to use [Bayesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization#/Bayesian_optimization) HPO all the way, which in a way does it for you. For `python` it's available in [`scikit-optimize`](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/notebooks/bayesian-optimization.html) package.